# Friedel-Crafts acylation of furan

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds

Can [furan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furan) undergo [Friedel–Crafts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedel%E2%80%93Crafts_reaction) acylation with benzoyl chloride?

Some people say it will have no reaction. Is it true?

If so, why cannot it undergo Friedel–Crafts acylation like other ketones?

Answer (score 4):

> Classical Friedel-Crafts acylation conditions fail completely in the case of the sensitive and polymerization-prone furan, or give only rather unsatisfying yields only.

Quoted from the abstract of this recent paper$\ce{^{[1]}}$ which describes a mild method for the acylation of furans with free carboxylic acids. Furan is not very stable to classical F-C conditions with $\ce{AlCl3}$. $\ce{BF3}$ is a better catalyst$\ce{^{[2]}}$.

**References**

1. Martina Opietnik, Alois Jungbauer, Kurt Mereiter and Thomas Rosenau, “Mild Friedel-Crafts Acylation of Furan with Carboxylic Acids and the Heterogeneous Catalyst Couple AlPW12O40 / Mg(OH)2”, Current Organic Chemistry (**2012**) 16: 2739. DOI: [https://doi.org/10.2174/138527212804004490](https://www.eurekaselect.com/104883/article)
2. THE ACYLATION OF FURAN AND THIOPHENE WITH ALIPHATIC ANHYDRIDES IN THE PRESENCE OF BORON TRIFLUORIDE-ETHERATE by JOHN V. HEID and ROBERT LEVINE
   The Journal of Organic Chemistry, **1948** 13 (3), 409-412
   DOI: [10.1021/jo01161a015](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo01161a015)

Comment: Sir, I was wondering will chlorobenzene undergo fridel crafts acylation reaction as chlorine exerts both (-I) effect and (+M) effect?

Comment: Yes it will. Here is an example https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403998008818